# Ensuring security of my files at web server

Tags: security, webserver, lockfile

I have hosted my website on a shared web-hosting server. However, I am worried about the security of the files that I have kept on the server. Admins of web-hosting service keep on changing the contents of my cron jobs etc. by their own. I am worried if they change my files also some day.

Is there any way to lock my folders on web-server so that no one else can have access to it as we have folder-locker in Windows.

Any other suggestions are also welcomed in this regard.

Thanks !

Comment: Admins own the box. Whatever you do, they will beat you in the end if they want to. Did you tried to find out why they change your cronjob? Maybe they are trying to 'fix' something that is not broken.

Comment: They are reducing my CPU usages even when I am well within my limits

Comment: Will having a dedicated server would help me ?

Comment: A dedicated server would help, still, if it is a virtual server the hoster might still want to have root-access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as you are hosting your website remotely you are restricted to the policy of the hosting provider..

rather than trying to restrict administrators from accessing your files, you can work other way round by encrypting your files so that it would be difficult for them to modify the functionality..

but above all administrators are there to help you, and not to hinder your development or progress so even if they have done some changes to your files, it would have been definitely for your and others' benefit who are sharing the hosting on the same server with you..